# Xcode UITableView sections and rows sorted by date (from mutableArray)

Tags: ios, sorting, tableview, rows, sections

In my UITableView i have multiple secions with date titles.
the dates are sorted by date in a NSMutableArray.
my sections are showing the correct dates, that works fine, and the numberofrowsinnsection works fine too.
For the cells textlabels I got NSMutableArrays that are sorted in the same order like the sorted dates.
How do I get the correct textlabel for the corresponding date(section)?
With indexpath.section it works only when there is 1 row in a section. When i got 2 or more rows in a section the textlabels have wrong values. 
i understand that this could be done with dictionaries, but i couldn´t find a solution.

```
@property NSMutableArray *dateArray;     //date for my sections
@property NSMutableArray *hoursArray;   //hours for cells textlabel
```

my sections

```
"January 2014",
"April 2014",
"June 2014"
```

my hours:

```
"1",
"2",
"3",
```

///////////EDIT

When i use
Cell.textlabel.text =[hoursarray objectatindex:indexpath.row]
It always starts at index 0 in every section.

When i use
Cell.textlabel.text =[hoursarray objectatindex:indexpath.section]
It has the correct sorting when there is only 1 row each section. 
But when there are more rows in a section, the order is wrong

Comment: Can you elaborate it lil more?

Comment: See the edit, is it comprehensible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your datasource sorted so just create a sectionArray of rowArray and then use it accordingly.
Then you can use it like this:

```
Cell.textlabel.text = [[sectionArray objectatindex:indexpath.section] objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
```

Now you just need to manage your datasource aacordingly.

**UPDATED:**
  You can create 2D array like this

```
NSMutableArray *dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for(int i=0; i<=dateData.length; i++)
{
   NSMutableArray *hoursArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   for(int j=0; j<=hoursData.length; j++)
   {
     [hoursArray addObject:yourObject];
   }

   [dateArray addObject:hoursArray];
}
```

This is just an example, however you can optimize according to your need.

Comment: i sorted the dates array using sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]; after that i sort the hoursarray in ordering of the dates array... but when is use your code [[sectionArray objectatindex:indexpath.section] objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]; the app crashes for the error: -[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.  do i need a 2 dimensional array ?

Comment: @user2912794 Yeah THat what I have mentioned 2D array.. dateArray containg hoursArray..

Comment: could you please show me an example how the 2d array should look like ?

Comment: I think i got it, each section needs its own array containing its data and this array i add to a "main" array!?